# Cannot print values in C++ Xcode Project

Tags: c++, xcode, debugging

I am unable to print out information in the console while running C++ projects.  For example, if I am at a breakpoint in a given function where I have previously declared
`vector<ValueTerm> heap;` and have since pushed some values, if I want to check the current size with a command `print heap.size()`, I get the following error:

> print heap.size()
>   error: call to a function 'std::__1::vector, std::__1::allocator > >::size() const' ('_ZNKSt3__16vectorINS_4pairIjjEENS_9allocatorIS2_EEE4sizeEv') that is not present in the target
>   error: 0 errors parsing expression
>   error: The expression could not be prepared to run in the target

I have no found much information regarding this on the internet and am wondering if I am missing something, doing something wrong or simply have a faulty setup of C++ or some compiler flags not properly set.

Comment: Please **[edit]** your question with a [mcve] or [SSCCE (Short, Self Contained, Correct Example)](http://sscce.org)

Comment: for printing in C++ use std::cout . to print heap.size() you can do : std::cout<<heap.size(); MAke ure you include iostream header file

Comment: @Ravi I am referring to printing things out in the debugger at runtime.